# WPF: Loading resource directory from file throws exception 'Initialization of System.Windows.Setter'

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a skinnable backgammon application in WPF, which works fine, as long as i include the skin file (=resource directory) in the project and compile it within the assembly. However, when i remove the skin file from the project and try to load it from file at runtime, i get the following error : 'Initialization of 'System.Windows.Setter' threw an exception'.

This is the code behind to load the resource directory that is included in the project (working fine) :

```
private void SetSkin(string SkinName)
    {
        Collection<ResourceDictionary> appResources;
        appResources = App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;
        ResourceDictionary skin = new ResourceDictionary();
        try
        {
            Uri skinUri = new Uri(SkinName + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            skin.Source = skinUri;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Loading the skin " + SkinName + ":\n" + e.Message, "Unable to load skin", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        appResources.Add(skin);
        if (_CurrentSkin != null) appResources.Remove(_CurrentSkin);
        _CurrentSkin = skin;
    }
```

When i change the Uri to the code below in order to load the skin at runtime, i get the error : 'Initialization of 'System.Windows.Setter' threw an exception'

```
Uri skinUri = new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Skins\\" + SkinName + "\\" + SkinName + ".xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

The error happens on the the following setter in the skin file :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BackgammonView">

<Style x:Key="MainGrid" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="local:BgBoardView.GridRows" Value="44*,45*,45*,22*,32*,10*,42*,10*,32*,22*,45*,45*,43*"/>
</Style>
```

The string above sets the row definitions of the main grid via an attached property 'GridRows' of the class BgBoardView (which is the window).

This is the XAML of the window and the main grid :

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:BackgammonView.Properties"
    x:Class="BackgammonView.BgBoardView" x:Name="MainWindow"
    Icon="SkinBackgammon.ico" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    Style="{DynamicResource MainWindow}" Closing="MainWindow_Closing">

<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Style="{DynamicResource MainGrid}">
```

The code works fine as long as i include and compile the resource directory in the project. This is the code to set the row definitions of the grid :

```
namespace BackgammonView
{
    public partial class BgBoardView : Window
    {
        private static DependencyProperty GridRowsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GridRows", typeof(string),
          typeof(BgBoardView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange,
          new PropertyChangedCallback(GridRowsChanged)));
        public static string GetGridRows(Grid Grid) { return Convert.ToString(Grid.GetValue(GridRowsProperty)); }
        public static void SetGridRows(Grid Grid, string Value) { Grid.SetValue(GridRowsProperty, Value); }
        private static void GridRowsChanged(Object Sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid Grid = (Grid)Sender;
            string[] sGridLength = GetGridRows(Grid).Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
            GridLengthConverter convert = new GridLengthConverter();
            Grid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < sGridLength.Length; i++)
            {
                GridLength GridLength = (GridLength)convert.ConvertFromString(sGridLength[i]);
                RowDefinition rowdef = new RowDefinition();
                rowdef.Height = GridLength;
                Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowdef);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue why this won't work when i dynamically load the resource directory at runtime?

Any help is much appreciated. Tx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the assembly in your `xmlns:local` definition. When you're loading it from the compiled assembly that part gets resolved for you from the containing assembly but when loading as a loose file it doesn't have a containing assembly to use.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thanks ! Changed the local definition to xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BackgammonView;assembly=SkinBackgammon" and now it works fine.